# openssl SHA512 library in C return different digest for the same input

Tags: c, openssl, sha

I notice that in my code, for the same string that I hash with SHA512, I got different digest, I know that impossible. I don't see what is wrong in my code. first, I create some random string, lets call it private key. than I hash private key and get public key. I attach simplify code, just for the clearance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define KEY_SIZE 512 //number of bits in the key

void key_gen(unsigned char *secret_key, unsigned char *public_key) {
    
    RAND_bytes(secret_key, KEY_SIZE);
    SHA512(secret_key, KEY_SIZE, public_key);
    }

void sign(unsigned char *message, unsigned char *signature, unsigned char *secret_key){
    memcpy(signature, secret_key, KEY_SIZE);
}
int verify(unsigned char *message, unsigned char *signature, unsigned char *public_key){
    unsigned char check_public_key[KEY_SIZE];
    SHA512(signature, KEY_SIZE, check_public_key);
    if(memcmp(check_public_key, public_key, KEY_SIZE) != 0){
        printf("not valid");
        return 0;
    }
    
    printf("valid");
    return 1;
}

int main() {

    //key pair
    unsigned char secret_key [KEY_SIZE];
    unsigned char public_key [KEY_SIZE];
    key_gen(secret_key, public_key);

    //message
    unsigned char message[] = "Hello World";

    //signature
    unsigned char signature [KEY_SIZE];
        
    sign(message, signature, secret_key);

    //verify the signature

    verify(message, signature, public_key);

    return 0;
}
```

It should return 1, because public key is just result of the digest of the private key.

I expecting to print valid and return 1, because I just comparing between SHA512(signature) and public_key , which is the same thing. the signature is just the secret_key, and public_key is SHA512(secret_key). I dont know, I THINKK something is wrong here `SHA512(signature, KEY_SIZE, check_public_key);` , but this is how I can use SHA512.

Comment: because you're comparing 512 bytes but the SHA512 signature is only 32 bytes; the rest of them are random garbage data that's probably different both times

Comment: You have mixed up bits and bytes.

Comment: As I knew, signature , secret_key and public_key are with size of 512 bits or size of  KEY_SIZE. i might be wrong but I use the KEY_SIZE in the SHA512 function. no sure if I understand.

Comment: Do you know the difference between bits and bytes? `unsigned char secret_key [KEY_SIZE];` is an arrays of `512` *bytes*. `memcmp(...., KEY_SIZE)` is comparing `512` *bytes*. `512` bytes is `4096` bits.

Comment: as i understand, instead of KEY_SIZE OF 512 , I can use KEY_SIZE 512/8

Comment: Can and should.